# Is there a bundle in Symfony 3 for a site-wide search?

Tags: php, symfony, search

I would like to create a search on a site that if possible would look at both public and private areas to complete a search. The only search for Symfony I can find is http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/search/introduction.html and support for it stopped a long time ago.

Is there anything that has taken over from this project?

I would have liked to have used something like the elastic stack etc, however, I am running this site on a cPanel account, therefore I do not have permission to install applications on the server (unless in something like installatron). Are there any Symfony bundles anywhere that can do a scan of your site and index searches? Or maybe something that will do the front end and do a live search of the content of your site if its a CMS held in the database or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to install ElasticSearch and the [FOS/ElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle).

If the learning curve is too hard for you, you can also check [Algolia](https://github.com/algolia/AlgoliaSearchBundle) which is great and have great support.

Finally you have the option to put the Google Search Box on your site with zero effort.

Comment: As stated in the question, this is on a cPanel account, so I can not install applications (unless they use composer or installatron), so ElasticSearch is out. Unless of course I could somehow install the ElasticaBundle on the cpanel machine and ElasticSearch on a local machine that would go offline when the net drops out (and would not be as fast), but I'm guessing there is nothing you can do to stop the search going down? Algolia looks interesting and looks to be all web based (just a composer install) from what I can see. The demo on their site seems fast and customizable as well.

Comment: Actually, looking closer, Algolia is a hosted solution, and I'm guessing that doing a full site search would be too much for their free plan, we want something opensource if possible. At the moment it may be a case of customizing a live search myself and just searching live on the system (will be a bit slower than an indexed one and take longer to build/implement but will show the best results at no cost).